# Play 2.5 Errors with Java 8 - wrong number of type arguments and lambda expression not expected here error

Tags: java-8, playframework-2.5

I'm attempting to upgrade from Play 2.4 to Play 2.5. Using the guide from the [Replaced F.Promise with Java 8's CompletionStage](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/releases/release25/migration25/JavaMigration25.md), I replaced `F.Promise`, `map`, and `flatMap` with the suggested replacements from the previous link (reflected snippet of changes below).

```
  public CompletionStage<Result> parallel() {
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final CompletionStage<WSResponse, Long> getLatency = resp -> System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    CompletionStage<Long> googleLatency = WS.url("http://google.com").get().thenApplyAsync(getLatency);
    CompletionStage<Long> yahooLatency = WS.url("http://yahoo.com").get().thenApplyAsync(getLatency);

    return googleLatency.thenComposeAsync(googleResponseTime ->
            yahooLatency.thenApplyAsync(yahooResponseTime ->
                ok(format("Google response time:  %d; Yahoo response time:  %d",
                    googleResponseTime, yahooResponseTime)))
    );
  }
```

After running `./activator clean dist`, I'm getting the error below:

> [error] /Play-2-JS-2.5/app/controllers/Java8Controller.java:74: wrong number of type arguments; required 1
>   [error] CompletionStage
>   [error] /Play-2-JS-2.5/app/controllers/Java8Controller.java:74: lambda expression not expected here
>   [error] resp -> System.currentTimeMillis() - start

For some reason, it believes it should have only one instead of two in the `CompletionStage<WSResponse, Long> getLatency` section and also for some reason it's not liking the lambda expression even though the syntax before the new api replacements worked successfully in Play 2.4.

I tried switching back to the old calls to what is displayed in https://github.com/btgrant-76/Play-2-Java-Scala-Java-8-Async-Comparison/blob/6a85cf31cfb804ef20bacf8e14d30ce46cc9307c/app/controllers/Java8Controller.java#L71-L83 however it doesn't lend any better results. Been googling and searching for sometime but not sure how to approach this. Any suggestions with possible examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
final CompletionStage<WSResponse, Long> getLatency = resp ->
        System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

with

```
final Function<WSResponse, Long> getLatency = resp -> System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

since `thenApplyAsync` metod in `CompletionStage` interface accepts a `java.util.Function`

Hope this helps.
Good luck

Comment: Glad to know it helped